# Access variable inside block

Tags: ruby, block, rubymotion

I'm using a certain block in RubyMotion and trying to access an instance variables inside of it which was declared outside. It turns out I can't access the variable from the inside. Is there any obvious solution I'm missing here? Thanks!

Here is the code

```
@my_var = true

Dispatch::Queue.concurrent.async do
  # can't access @my_var here
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that `async` runs the block with `instance_eval`, so your instance variable is binding to some other object when used inside the block. If you only need to read the variable, just use a local copy inside the block

```
@my_var = true
my_var = @my_var
Dispatch::Queue.concurrent.async do
  my_var
end
```

or if you have an accessor method

```
@my_var = true
this = self
Dispatch::Queue.concurrent.async do
  this.my_var
end
```

Comment: Yes that worked, thanks a lot for the explanation! Interesting fact that local variables can be accessed while instance vars can't...

Comment: Local variables are always accessible inside a block. `instance_eval` only changes the value of `self` inside the block. Thus my first example would fail if the `instance_eval` receiver had an instance method called `my_var`.